# Why does Karen speak three different languages?

Tags: dialogue, ichi-the-killer

In Ichi the Killer, Karen, played by Alien Sun, speaks three different languages throughout the film.    Most of her dialog is a mix of English and Japanese, going so far as to speak one line in English, followed immediately by a line in Japanese.

In many of these cases it's not entirely clear that those around her understand the English.

Later, when sitting in her car before meeting Ichi, she speaks outloud to herself in what sounds like Chinese.

Is there a reason her character mixes languages like this?